# forcing order of prerequisites in Makefiles

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a third party makefile, and I'd like one of the targets (T1) to not be built until another, custom target (T2) is built first.  Normally, this would be accomplished by making T2 a prerequisite of T1.  BUT, T1 uses the $^ in one of its rules.. so, by adding the prerequisite, I end up breaking the build...  What I have is this:

```
T1: x y z T2
    $(MAKE) -j $^;
    # fails because T2 should not be passed to the make!!!

.PHONY: T2

T2:
    #do some linking and prep for T1
```

Is there a good way to ensure that T2 is run before T1?  (Note: the above example is actually simplified by a bit.  T1 is actually the vmlinux target within the Linux kernel makefile, so rewriting it is not only difficult, it makes the code non-portable.  Also, I can't run T2 before calling make on the kernel due to some other dependencies).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Have T2 as an [order-only prerequisite](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Prerequisite-Types):

```
T1: x y z | T2
    $(MAKE) -j $^;
    # Make will run the T2 rule before this one, but T2 will not appear in $^
```

Comment: While this does work, according to the Makefile documentation (at http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html), $^ contains all of the prerequisites, except for duplicates.  Thus T2 should be in $^ (though it's not).  So is this standard behavior, or is this a bug?   i.e, can I count on this working on different versions of make, including future ones?

Comment: Ok, retract that last one.  Apparently $^ is described twice at that url -- once it mentions that order-only's are not included, the other time it doesn't.  I'll fire off an email to the document owners to let them know.

Comment: The second description of `$^` is just and quick reference appendix. The first one described as it:
> This list does **not** contain any of the order-only prerequisites; for those see the `$|` variable

Comment: BTW, if there're multiple order-only prerequisites `| A B C`, are they built in order of `A > B > C`?

Comment: @nn0p: AFAIK the order in which they are built is not specified; they might well go in order, but don't count on it.

Answer (score 1):

Could you just call Make in your build script with the two targets in the proper order, e.g.

```
make T2 T1
```

That way you don't need to make any modifications to T1.

Comment: The above comment is extremely important. (And the problem it highlights is causing me no end of headaches and making serial `make` look appealing, despite the 8x slowdown that'll entail. Well, I put up with it for long enough before...)